# Dart: несколько одиннаковых параметров в http запросе

Tags: flutter, dart

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией, мне во флаттере необходимо сделать get запрос с множеством параметров. Один из таких параметров может/должен быть включён несколько раз. Но так как мы его наполняем через мап, у нас конфликтуют ключи. Чёт адекватные решения не приходят в голову. Может у кого есть идеи?

```
var res = await _client.get("/single", queryParameters: {
    "param1": "p",
    "param2": "p2",
    "dt": "t",
    "dt": "rm",
    "dt": "rt",
  });
```

P.S. для http запросов использую Dio.

Comment: Не знаю как в дарте, но обычно в таких случаях используют массивы

Comment: Дело в том что аргументы принимает только в виде Map<String, dynamic>.

Comment: Ну так `{"dt":["t","rm","tr"]}` вполне себе dynamic

Comment: А как бек такое обрабатывает? Он же не сможет понять что записано в `dt`. Вариант @AlexeyTen, более менее нормальный. Еще можно одной строкой: `"dt": "t;rm;rt"`

Comment: Ну или вообще сделать так:  `_client.get("/single?param1=p&param2=p2&dt=t&dt=rm&dt=rt");` Собирать такие строки можно через [StringBuffer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое решение должно работать с get запросом:

```
void main() {
  getSingle("p", "p2", <String>["t", "rm", "rt"]); // "/single?param1=p&param2=p2&dt=t&dt=rm&dt=rt"
}

void getSingle(String param1, String param2, List<String> dt) {
  final StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
  buffer.write("/single");
  buffer.write("?param1=$param1"); // ? используем так как он первый
  buffer.write("&param2=$param2"); // & используем для соединения

  for (String item in dt) {
    buffer.write("&dt=$item");
  }

  print(buffer.toString()); // var res = await _client.get(buffer.toString());
}
```

Ну или вообще сделать так:  `_client.get("/single?param1=p&param2=p2&dt=t&dt=rm&dt=rt");`

Comment: Спасибо, напомнили как гет можно сделать) Вы предложили вариант в комментарии к вопросу, добавьте и его в ответ пожалуйста, так как он будет на порядок проще.